# DNS over OpenVPN from PFsense only working when in Full DNS (Use VPN DNS for all traffic)

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, openvpn, pfsense

I configured a DNS Resolver in our PFsense which I also provide as part of the DNS Server list to clients via OpenVPN. Clients can connect via OpenVPN and also resolve local names via the DNS Resolver but only if the VPN Client DNS Setting is set to Full DNS (Use VPN DNS for all traffic). The client is Viscosity on macOS and the default setting is Automatic which doesn't work.

That said, all windows machines with the default OpenVPN client work out of the box. I am not sure what would be important to share to resolve this issue but did anyone see such a behaviour? What could be misconfigured that the local names are not solved if I don't use the VPN for all traffic?

Any hint is welcome